# Looping in Python for a beginner

Tags: python, loops

I am new to coding and looking for a simple way to implement a loop in python. Here is an example of my code! I need to define variables u,v,w etc. from 1 through to 12 to carry out my regression analysis, hence why a loop would be ideal. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
dataset = pd.read_csv("MultipleRegression.csv")

x1 = np.append(arr = np.ones((4, 1)).astype(int), values = x1, axis = 1)
x_opt1 = x1[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
regressor_OLS1 = sm.OLS(endog = y1, exog = x_opt1).fit()
regressor_OLS1.summary()
u1 = regressor_OLS1.params[1]
v1 = regressor_OLS1.params[2]
w1 = regressor_OLS1.params[3]
x1 = regressor_OLS1.params[4]
y1 = regressor_OLS1.params[5]
z1 = regressor_OLS1.params[6]
```

Comment: You are new to coding with python or to general coding ? We normally start with `hello world` and not `regression analysis`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can do that without a loop, just unpack the parameters:

```
u1,v1 ,w1 ,x1 ,y1 ,z1, *rest = regressor_OLS1.params
```